# How to access Rails test helper code from the console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testcase

Using vanilla ActiveSupport::TestCase, I've added several helper methods that generate test model objects in test/test_helper.rb. In this file is a reopening of ActiveSupport::TestCase that contains the helper methods.

Now suppose I'm in the Ruby Console (or pry, with the Rails environment loaded), and I want to fiddle with these test methods. I can load the file: load "test/test_helper.rb" but I can't create a TestCase instance that will let me access those test methods to play with them:

```
[4] pry(main)> tc = ActiveSupport::TestCase.new
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
[5] pry(main)> tc = ActiveSupport::TestCase.new(1)
TypeError: 1 is not a symbol
[6] pry(main)> tc = ActiveSupport::TestCase.new(:unit)
ArgumentError: uncaught throw :invalid_test
```

I've tried in vain to follow the trail of breadcrumbs in source files to find the TestCase initialize method so I could figure out what it's insisting on here.

Can someone help me with how to think about problems like this and figure out a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Copied from this link: https://gist.github.com/1297510

On your terminal type:

```
RAILS_ENV=test pry
```

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case, in my version of ActiveSupport (3.22.2.8), I was able to do the following:

```
ActiveSupport::TestCase.new('some_string')
```

In general though, there's several options:

- using a debugger like `pry` can be helpful, to step through the issue.
- find the source code via `gem open activesupport` or find where your gems are installed with `gem environment`
- most gems are open source and are easily found on github.com, etc.  Just be careful that you're looking at the correct version.